# Server got InternalServerError, but device receive the notification

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

I implemented a GCM server to send notification, as well as a GCM Android client to receive notification.
Most of the time, they were working good. But some times the server got InternalServerError response, like that:

{"multicast_id":7727132596694632507,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"InternalServerError"}]}

When got this reponse, 
1. some times the device can not receive notification.
2. but some times the device can receive notification(event InternalServerError responsed).

I know should retry send when got InternalServerError. But that may cause duplicated notification sending for the situation 2. 
How to resolve that?

Comment: You are doing a multicast. That response array will sometimes have success for some items and failure for others. Are you quite sure that the GCM is being recieved by the ID that corresponds to the error status?

Comment: Thanks for respond. I only give one registration id in the request like: {
  "to" : "APA91bHun\BaFUH-1RYqx...",
  "data" : {
    ...
  },
}  The GCM should be received that, and return InternalServerError but my device indeed got the notification. That is the problem.

Comment: If you are sending only to a single user why are you using the multicast end point?